# jQuery SlideUp Flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website for a friend using Cargo Collective:

http://cargocollective.com/joaocanziani

I'm having some issues with a dropdown menu that uses 'SlideUp' and 'SlideDown'. I have read a few problems regarding 'flickering' here, the issue is I am not seeing the problem on any of my devices in any browsers. My friend sent me a video of the problem, which you can see here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34804399/video.mov

The user sees the problem in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome (all on OS X). I have not been able to replicate the problem on any device, making it difficult to troubleshoot. Given what I saw, ti seems like the problem could be with the jQuery slide, but I'm not sure where I've gone amiss.

```
// Slide Down On Load       
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).load(function(){
      $('.navigation_tag').each(function(i){
          $(this).delay(1200).slideUp(500);
      });
   });
});    

// Slide Up On Scroll   
$(document).scroll(function(){
  // Hide Navigation when page reaches more than 50 on scroll
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= 10)
  {
      $(".navigation_tag").slideUp(500);
  }
  if($(this).scrollLeft() >= 10)
  {
      $(".navigation_tag").slideUp(500);
  }    
});

// Slide Down On Hover 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.heading a').bind('mouseenter', function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'mouseenter':
           // when user enters the div
           $(".navigation_tag").slideDown(500);
        break;
    }
});
});    

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.navigation').bind('mouseleave', function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case 'mouseleave':
           // when user enters the div
           $(".navigation_tag").slideUp(500);
        break;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Is there anyone else, besides your friend, who has this issue?

Comment: I have not been able to, nor anyone I have sent it to. Part of posting it here is I am trying to isolate and see if the issue may be on his end alone. It is curious it works in Chrome for him, but not Safari / Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it, but it looks like you're using jQuery 1.4.2, which is a little old. If you try update it, does he still get this behaviour?

Comment: Insofar as I can gather from Cargo, they run on jQuery 1.4.2. Running a newer version of jQuery breaks a lot of their scripting that I can't affect. Is it possible I could utilize a newer version of jQuery only for this affect, and not for other parts of the site? I've never tried to use two versions like that and know it's a bit frowned upon.

Comment: I have tried to add .stop() functions, e.g., .stop().slideDown(500), as a possible way I've seen here to resolve the problem. It still does not appear to work.